# Testing code on a new server: java.time.localdatetime cannot be converted to date. It does not happen in production

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, mariadb

- I am setting up a development server on an [AWS AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html) with [ColdFusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion) 2018 and MariaDB 10.5.4
- I did not find out what the current production versions were, but it is highly possible they were somewhat older. The application was launched in 2016
- The code is unchanged from production, and the database is a direct backup and restore, no changes
- I am getting errors in the code in the `cfoutput` query when it tries to format the field Named: DateStamp.  This is one example of the code that errors. It is in many places:

  ```
  #DateFormat(Q.DateStamp,"m/d/yyyy")# #TimeFormat(Q.DateStamp, "short")#
  ```
- This is the error

  - "The value class `java.time.LocalDateTime` cannot be converted to a date"
- The table in MariaDB has the datatype of DateStamp as datetime, and this is unchanged from production

I don't know why this is expecting the field to be a LocalDateTime when it is a regular DateTime.  It has to be something in the configuration of this environment, but I'm having trouble understanding what. I have searched, but all I get is "how to handle LocalDateTime" type of links, so it isn't of any help as I can't change all the code when this is a test environment that must at least start with the same code as production

Comment: What is the value of Q.DateStamp?

Comment: `select Q.DateStamp from <table> where <id = a single>` <br />
example looks like "2016-10-17 17:50:34"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment on [Adrian's contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997681/testing-code-on-a-new-server-java-time-localdatetime-cannot-be-converted-to-dat/66001018#66001018)—in cases like this the answer is often found by comparing the datasource configuration between environments—most importantly whether the same database driver was chosen in both, and then the various advanced settings on the datasource, and finally any version/compatibility settings on the database server itself.

Comment: thank you, coldfusion, java and mariaDB are not my most familiar territory

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out which versions of [ACF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion), MySQL and Java are running in production. Even if the application was launched in 2016, there isn’t any guarantee it was released on [ColdFusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion) 2016. It could be an older version of the server.

> select Q.DateStamp from  where <id = a single> 
>  example looks like "2016-10-17 17:50:34"

Did you run the query in an IDE or did you run this through a `cfquery`? You need to make sure that it's returning as a DateTime object (`{ts '2012-12-12 12:12:12'}`) and not a string.

[java.time.localDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.

[MariaDB DateTime](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/#:%7E:text=MariaDB%20stores%20values%20that%20use,0%20is%20used%20by%20default.)

> MariaDB displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ffffff'

Comment: Well thanks for the link to localDateTime.  Somewhere I read that it included the timezone but I'm sure it was not the actual documentation. I'm caught by RTFM again, drat.

Comment: In addition to which versions of CF, SQL and Java, it's also worth comparing the CF datasource settings used and which DB driver was used, and check for any differences in version/compatibility settings on the DB server configuration itself.

Comment: @SevRoberts Write your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the answer because you are right on, the problem was the last time I used MariaDB was when it was new and nearly everything that worked with mysql worked with MariaDB.  Now though it's important to use the actual MariaDB driver. A friend of mine changed the driver and it works perfectly now.  As soon as he said it I thought, yea that makes more sense than any path I was going down.