# strange issue with coldfusion 2021 datetime as it shows java dump

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I am using mysql and one of the column has a datetime datatype, when i do a output, it actually displays a java class,

```
https://prnt.sc/10sgstg
```

so why it is displaying a java class, do i need to cast something to understand it to display date or it is a bug

Comment: How are you outputting it to the screen?

Comment: like this: <cfoutput>#myquery.invitedate#</cfoutput>

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, and which DB driver has been chosen in the datasource configuration in CF Admin?

Comment: i am using `10.1.28-MariaDB` i have mysql 5 from the cfadmin

Comment: In that case try using the MariaDB specific driver instead of the MySQL driver for your datasource. Your issue sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997681/testing-code-on-new-server-java-time-localdatetime-cannot-be-converted-to-date/66001018

Comment: so connect with odbc instead of mysql/

Comment: No, stick with JDBC. Sounds like all you need is the correct jdbc driver.  From what I remember of using ODBC connections is that they were slower and more finicky than pure JDBC. Not to mention they require installing a separate CF service.

Comment: so which one is correct jdbc driver for  this database , do you have any link or anything which i can use

Comment: Depends on the version of MySQL you're running. (You forgot to include that information in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

i changed the mysql j/connector and it started working, because in my case the connector was 8.0 and i was connecting to mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Using Mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar resolves this.

You can download it from here https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/

Unzip it and copy the .jar file to this location .../Coldfusion2021/cfusion/lib

Remove any existing Mysql-connector-java-xxxxxx.jar file from that folder

Restart Coldfusion

Dates should work as expected once again